# SQL Command from Variable for MDX OLEDB source SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas, mdx

I'm having some issues with an MDX query source in an SSIS data flow.

If I configure an OLEDB source properly, and have the data access mode as SQL Command, the MDX query works.

I need this source to be parameterized though, so I'm trying to pass in a variable that is populated at runtime as the MDX source query.

The problem is, when I set this up, it will try to use the variable (which is not  correct until runtime) and throw this error.

What is the trick to getting an MDX Source to work from a variable?

I built all of the downstream transformations after first configuring the source with a hardcoded query (SQL Command). Then I went back to change the source to use the variable and it broke.

Thanks for any input.

```
TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio
------------------------------

The component reported the following warnings:

Error at DFT SSAS to SQL [SRC SSASPRP01 Cube [2]]: No column information was returned by the SQL command.


Choose OK if you want to continue with the operation.
Choose Cancel if you want to stop the operation.

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
Cancel
------------------------------
```

Comment: Maybe try putting the static parts of your query into two different variable. Then you have your parameter in a third variable. Then the query variable would be the concatenation of all three strings. It shouldn't matter, then, if your parameter value isn't available until runtime.

Comment: Try setting delay validation for dataflow and the OLDDB source both True.

Comment: @Scotch any luck with setting both the DatFlow and the Connection DelayValidation=True?

Answer (score 1):

You want to a parameterized query and would like to build a String variable with the query. Anyway, your package needs to be validated before run. So, here you have two options:

- If your query variable is populated at runtime and it has no Expressions, you might specify this variable value with a valid MDX query. The package and your DataFlow task will be validated before run (regular process)with this default query and pass, and at runtime - use correct MDX query.
- You can set *DelayValidation* property of your DataFlow task to **true**. Then it will be validated immediately before running, when your variable will contain valid MDX query.

I would prefer the second method as more generic.

Answer (score 0):

Set Delay Validation = True. Delay validation is a property available for all SSIS components and it basicly holds the validation back till excution. Mostly when we set connections or other components with variables it helps. As the variables dont have the true property at run time.

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but probably because this is more like a comment. I personally know of the delay validation setting and will try it, but it's not a very thorough answer. You may want to edit it to show how to do that, and explain why that is the solution. In the meantime, I'll try it and report back

Comment: This should have been a comment on the original question. And as Scotch said, not thorough at all.

Comment: Setting delay validation to true for the dataflow task did not prevent it from trying to validate the OLEDB Source. ValidateExternalMetadata on the source may help. I have it working by just validating it while the variable is set at design time to the result that I want.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22075365)

Comment: @CaptainMan, Please help me understand why this is not an answer. 1)The person asking says it helps , 2)There is another person giving the same answer 3)This is exactly that he needs to do. Setting this property will prevent validation and solve his issue.

Comment: @Scotch any luck with setting both the dataflow and the connection to Delayvalidation=True.